# Confused how if__name__ == '__main__' works

Tags: python

In the module 'test_name_function.py' as I am importing 'get_formatted_name' why is the if block getting executed

```
# name_function.py
def get_formatted_name(first,last):
    """Generate a neatly formatted name"""

    full_name = f"{first} {last}"
    return full_name.title()

# test_name_function.py
import unittest
from name_function import get_formatted_name

class NamesTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """Test for name_function.py"""

    def test_first_last_name(self):
        """DO names like 'Rajat Sharma' work"""
        formatted_name= get_formatted_name('rajat','sharma')
        self.assertEqual(formatted_name,'Rajat Sharma')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Because that `if` block is in the main module that you executed, not in the module that is being imported. I don't understand why you expect anything different. You might as well ask why `import unittest` doesn't stop the `if` block.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel- Sorry, but I am beginner and having hard time figuring out, when does importing a file or function would trigger the 'if __name__' block and when not. Thanks

Comment: The expectation seems a little unclear here, but the question has a clear and concise example, and it asks a question many new users have about a pretty obtuse bit of boilerplate. Users who need this question wouldn't be helped by the two page explanation of the precise background mechanics of the expression. This shouldn't be closed.

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_wlZ9IhbTs or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sugvnHA7ElY.

Comment: @PraveenPaliwal the if statement is always executed. The check ensures that the main function or unit test suite is only executed if it's the entry point from python. So `python test_name_function.py` would cause the suite to execute, but if you import from somewhere else, it won't execute.

Comment: @DanMonego You can't just look at the first answer and conclude it shouldn't be closed. The duplicate has **38** answers, all in varying quality and length. I don't see how adding more answers would be beneficial.

Comment: Thanks @DanMonego, I got it now.

Comment: There's nothing special about the `if` statement. All you need to know is how the variable `__name__` is set by the interpreter. The purpose of the `if` statement flows pretty naturally from that.

Comment: Importing a module in the file where you have `if __name__ == '__main__'` has nothing to do with it. The question is whether *this* file is the one you are running, or whether it was imported from somewhere *else*.